# How to paginate keys and values from Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, pagination, will-paginate

Idea:
I want to paginate result of hash by ten records(key->value) per page.
When I try to paginate object, it displays the error: Undefined method paginates for Hash.
I can paginate keys by this:

```
  def index
    @url = @base_url+'latest.json'+@api
    @response = HTTParty.get(@url)
    @latest_currencies = @response['rates'].sort.to_h
    @lc_keys = @latest_currencies.keys.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    @lc_values = @latest_currencies.values.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
```

But in view:

```
  table.table.table-condensed
    thead
      tr
        th Waluta
        th Kurs
    tbody
      - @lc_keys.each do |k, v|
        tr
          td
            = k
          td
            = v
      = will_paginate @lc_keys
```

paginate only keys and not display values.
How can I paginate keys and values and return this in view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- @lc_keys.each do |k|
    tr
      td
        = k
      td
        = @latest_currencies[k]
```

or

```
@lc = @latest_currencies.to_a.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

- @lc.each do |k, v|
    tr
      td
        = k
      td
        = v
= will_paginate @lc
```